# vi - How go to line N?

Tags: vi

In vi editor how do I go to a particular line?

For example if I open a file named file.py is there an option for open the file at a particular line, or can I open my file and then go to line with keyboard shortcut?

Comment: You are welcome here and got your answer. Just an advice for the future: With `man vi` you can read the manual page. With `/line` you can search for occurences of the word `line`, with `n` jump to the next one, just like in `vi`. One of the first matches describes the option you were looking for. This takes less time than searching the web or asking a question here.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

To make vi start at a particular line in a file, add `+line_num` to the command you use to start vi. Replace `line_num` with the line number, for example:

```
vi +14 file.py
```

You can also use the ex command line to go to a line. (For information about the ex mode, see Use the vi text editor) For instance, if you wanted to go to line 14, you could press `Esc` and then enter:

```
:14
```

There is also a vi command.  The `G` jump (goto) motion takes an optional *count* prefix, which is the line number to go to.  Hence `14G`.
For the <kbd>kbd</kbd> addicts, that's
<kbd>1</kbd>, then <kbd>4</kbd>, and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: ...and you'd only press ESC if you weren't already in command mode (or you like your screen to flash)

Comment: You can also move around the file with relative offsets. For example from line 1 you can jump down (`j` or _cursor down_) 13 lines with `13j` (or `13` followed by _cursor down_). Upwards is with `k` or _cursor up_. You can jump up and down by page offsets too with the same principle

Comment: As long as we’re getting into the weeds: `13+` and `13` *`(Enter)`* will also move down 13 lines, similar to  `13j`, and you can use `13-` (minus) to go up 13 lines. A subtle difference: `j` and `k` are very much like `↓` (Cursor Down) and `↑` (Cursor Up); they will attempt to maintain the horizontal coordinate of the cursor’s position. `+`, `-` and *`(Enter)`*, on the other hand, will move the cursor to the first non-blank character on the destination line.

Comment: Still learning after years of use and still amazed at the awesome design decisions. `:14` was what I was looking for. Nice and simple. Less strokes than `14gg` and `14G`, with the benefit of seeing and editing what you type. Couldn't find it when I was searching with `:h gg` or `:h go`. (Anyone know how to find this in the help pages?)